# Book where alien boy crashes on Earth and communicates with deer

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, telepathy

I am looking for a book I read in the 1960s about an alien boy who crashes on Earth and is taken in by a human family. He also communicates telepathically with deer.

Comment: Not nearly enough information for an identification: deer telepathy was one of the most popular tropes of the 1960s.

Comment: possibly the same as (one of the stories in) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149580/1970s-sci-fi-short-story-in-4th-grade-reading-anthology

Answer (score 13):

*The Forgotten Door* by Alexander Key. 1965  Scholastic Books. A wonderful book that I just finished reading to my daughter and her friend. I had remembered it from when I first read it in 1968.

The boy falls through a forgotten "doorway" between worlds that had been long abandoned by his people. He loses his memory from the accident and is taken in by a family. He communicates telepathically with may animals and can read the minds of people with ease. His world is more advanced technologically and socially than ours, and has a back-to-basics lifestyle. The family tries to help the boy find the doorway so he can return home, while being harassed by the police and government who have their own interests in the boy.