# Book about an alien, with one of the plot points being baldness

Tags: story-identification, aliens

There was this book I read in (primary? < 2007) school that was about an alien, I think his name was Jon, who is found and is taken care of in a family. One of the plot points was someone was bald, either Jon or the family's daughter, and later in the story Jon manages to make whoever was bald grow hair.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: That sounds like The Forgotten Door by Alexander Key, except for the baldness. The alien boy is named Little Jon, and he's taken in by a family.

Comment: This looks like what I must be thinking of with Jon, I can't seem to remember where I got the baldness thing from though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1970's sci-fi short story in 4th grade reading anthology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149580/1970s-sci-fi-short-story-in-4th-grade-reading-anthology)