# Short story about kids going down a hole, from my English book in 1979

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was about these kids who went down into a hole and ended up in a different place. It started out at night with stars in the sky. I remember there was a mean old man, who was possibly a farmer. It was in my 6th grade English book around 1979.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Do you remember the title of your textbook?

Comment: If you hadn't said it was a short story I would have suggested _[The Weirdstone of Brisingamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Garner#The_Weirdstone_of_Brisingamen_and_The_Moon_of_Gomrath:_1957%E2%80%9364)_ but I confess I'm not sure exactly why as I haven't read it for many years.

Answer (score 5):

I'll guess that it's a short novel, it's only one kid, and it's *The Forgotten Door* by Alexander Key. It has an opening at night (looking at shooting stars) and the mean old farmer. (Also, it was issued by Scholastic, so likely to be encountered in school.)

Do the boy's telepathy, his being from a more peaceful society, a kind family that takes him in, and his wanting to go home sound right?

[image]

Comment: The whole novel actually appeared in a reading textbook of that period.  See here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149580/1970s-sci-fi-short-story-in-4th-grade-reading-anthology . That said, while this does match the question (except for the number of kids), this seems like an unusual combination of things to remember about *The Forgotten Door*.